# Why can't I compute the factorial of 100 in scala?

Tags: scala, factorial

I'm unit testing and I can't compute the factorial of 100. I read that using BigInt would help, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, because it still doesn't work.

Here is my function.

```
package Factorial{
class factorial
{
  def recursive_factorial(number:BigInt) : BigInt = 
   {
    if (number == 0)
      return 1
    number * recursive_factorial (number - 1)
  }
}
}
```

If I call the function with recursive_factorial(100).. I get an error that the number is too large for an int

Comment: If I take your code and add a suitable main method, it works fine, so presumably the error happens in the code that you didn't show. Please post a *runnable* piece of code that reproduces your problem and the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted works fine. The problem is the code you use to test your code (which you posted in a comment to another answer):

```
assertResult(93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264‌​38162146859296389521‌​75999932299156089414‌​63976156518286253697‌​92082722375825118521‌​09168640000000000000‌​00000000000) {
    factorial.recursive_factorial(100)
}
```

The problem is that integer literals have type `Int` and the number 93326... is obviously too large to fit into an int, so you can't use an integer literal to represent it.

One way to create a BigInt of a large number is to write it as a string and convert that to a `BigInt`. So this will work fine:

```
assertResult(BigInt("93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264‌​38162146859296389521‌​75999932299156089414‌​63976156518286253697‌​92082722375825118521‌​09168640000000000000‌​00000000000")) {
    factorial.recursive_factorial(100)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all, your function has the problem of causing a stackoverflow when number is too large. You should write it tail-recursively:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def recursive_factorial(number: BigInt, result: BigInt = 1): BigInt = {
  if (number == 0)
    result
  else
    recursive_factorial(number -1, result * number)
}
```

otherwise, your code example works perfectly for me and I don't know what your problem is. Probably, you try to write the result of this function (which is a `BigInt`) into an `Int` at some point which triggers the error.

Comment: I added this. {
   assertResult(93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000)
   {
     factorial.recursive_factorial(100)
   }
 }

Answer (score 0):

The function is just fine. Only limitation is the data type BigInt/BigInteger does not support arbitrary-precision point integer operation which can be done by BigDecimal. It works like a wrapper to BigInt. That's why instead of showing the big number it shows 9.332621544394415268169923885626674E+157. There is a discussion on which data type to use and when in the link below.

[Performace of BigDecimal vs. BigInteger and BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855321/performace-of-bigdecimal-vs-biginteger-and-bigdecimal)